# Fixing Class Error: "LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section"

Tags: errors, document-classes

I am attempting to install a new class file that my professional organization has provided for preparing journal article manuscripts. However, after installing it (by moving it into my local MiKTeX texmf tree and running "Refresh FNDP"), I cannot get the included .cls to work properly - even on the sample TEX document provided with it. The ZIP file which includes both the new class and tex files can be found [here](http://arc.aiaa.org/userimages/ContentEditor/1367257604835/AIAA_REVTeX41.ZIP?_ga=1.259851214.516308477.1470163466).

The error I get is "! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section." It is the only error I get when running the tex file included with the class file.

I've looked through a [few](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203387/declare-package-options-and-loading-packages-leads-to-options-section-error) [similar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271835/when-i-type-any-usepackage-i-get-the-error-requirepackage) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/latex-errors-requirepackage-or-loadclass-in-options-section-and-file-art) here, and learned enough to suspect that the problem is in the CLS file. However, I don't now enough about the structure of class files to fix it.

Could anyone offer any help?

Thank you very much!

Update: here is the code of the class file, as requested. I'm limiting it to the first 180 or so lines, because I've exceeded my character limit and that seems like a reasonable place to stop. The full class file can be downloaded from the AIAA at the link above.

```
%% Copyright notice.
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}%
%%%  @LaTeX-file{
%%%     version         = "x",
%%%     date            = "0000/00/00",
%%%     author          = "",
%%%     revised by      = ""
%%%     copyright       = ""
%%%     address         = "",
%%%     FAX             = "",
%%%     email           = "",
%%%     abstract        = "LaTeX Template for AAS journal submissions",
%%%  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{AIAA}%
\LoadClass[manuscript]{revtex4-1}[2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)]
\def\class@name{revtex4-1}%
%\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{revtex4}}%
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,oneside,onecolumn,final}%
\ProcessOptionsd
\RequirePackage{latexsym}%
\RequirePackage{graphicx}%
\RequirePackage{verbatim}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\normalsize{%
   \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{12}%
   \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
   \abovedisplayshortskip  \abovedisplayskip
   \belowdisplayshortskip \abovedisplayskip
   \let\@listi\@listI
}%
\def\small{%
  \@setfontsize\small\@ixpt{10.5}%
  \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus2\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
  \def\@listi{%
    \leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
    \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \itemsep \parsep
  }%
}%
\def\footnotesize{%
  \@setfontsize\footnotesize\@viiipt{9.5pt}%
  \abovedisplayskip 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus\p@
  \belowdisplayshortskip 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus2\p@
  \def\@listi{%
    \leftmargin\leftmargini
    \topsep 3\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \parsep 2\p@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
    \itemsep \parsep
  }%
}%
\def\scriptsize{%
 \@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt
}%
\def\tiny{%
 \@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt
}%
\def\large{%
 \@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14pt}%
}%
\def\Large{%
 \@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18pt}%
}%
\def\LARGE{%
 \@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{22pt}%
}%
\def\huge{%
 \@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25pt}%
}%
\def\Huge{%
 \@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30pt}%
}%
 \@ifxundefined\twoside@sw{\@booleanfalse\twoside@sw}{}%
 \twoside@sw{%
    \oddsidemargin  -20pt
    \evensidemargin -20pt
    \marginparwidth 107pt
 }{%
    \oddsidemargin  .15in
    \evensidemargin .15in
    \marginparwidth 30pt
 }%
\marginparsep 6pt
\topmargin -61pt
\headheight 25pt
\headsep 16pt
\topskip 10pt
\footskip 30pt
 \textheight = 56pc
\textwidth36pc
\columnsep 1.5pc
\columnseprule 0pt
\footnotesep 1pt
\skip\footins 39pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\def\footnoterule{\kern-19pt\hrule width.5in\kern18.6pt\relax}%
\floatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\textfloatsep 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\intextsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\dblfloatsep 12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt
\dbltextfloatsep 20pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
\@fptop 0pt plus 1fil
\@fpsep 8pt plus 2fil
\@fpbot 0pt plus 1fil
\@dblfptop 0pt plus 1fil
\@dblfpsep 8pt plus 2fil
\@dblfpbot 0pt plus 1fil
\marginparpush 5pt
\parskip 0pt plus 1pt
\parindent 1.5pc
\emergencystretch8\p@
\partopsep 2pt plus 1pt minus 1pt
\leftmargini 25pt
\leftmarginii 22pt
\leftmarginiii 18.7pt
\leftmarginiv 17pt
\leftmarginv 10pt
\leftmarginvi 10pt
\def\@listI{%
  \leftmargin\leftmargini
  \parsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@
  \topsep 8\p@ plus2\p@ minus4\p@
  \itemsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@
}%
\labelsep 4pt
\def\@listii{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginii
  \labelwidth\leftmarginii
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
  \topsep 4\p@ plus2\p@ minus\p@
  \parsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@
  \itemsep \parsep
}%
\def\@listiii{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginiii
  \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
  \topsep 2\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@
  \parsep \z@
  \partopsep \p@ plus\z@ minus\p@
  \itemsep \topsep
}%
\def\@listiv{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginiv
  \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
}%
\def\@listv{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginv
  \labelwidth\leftmarginv
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
}%
\def\@listvi{%
  \leftmargin\leftmarginvi
  \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
  \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% from class file
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That error seems to say that the class is badly written. It's not possible to say much more without seeing it.

Comment: Thank you!
I posted a link to download the original, but  here is a copy-paste of the file:

Edit: hit enter too early, and in any case, the code is obviously too long. I'll update the original post.

Comment: @amizener: The `.cls` file you provide is different to the one in the `.zip` file. There's also a `\ProcessOptionsd` error -- the command is called `\ProcessOptions`! Using the sample file from the zip archive and your version of the `.cls` (and removing the `d` in the mentioned command) the compilation is successful and does not give the error message

Comment: I get the error if I compile with `pdflatex`.  When compiling with  `xelatex`, it compiles fine.

Comment: @alwaysask: I just tried with LaTeX (instead of PdfLaTeX), and it works for me as well. Interesting.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Odd. That must have been a stray kestroke while I had it open. In any case, I updated the .cls with the master version, and I'm still getting the error except in LaTeX (instead of PdfLaTeX). Is there a way to fix the .cls file so that it works for PdfLaTeX too? The output looks cleaner to me.

Comment: In the class definition file I moved all nine `\DeclareOption...` commands starting line 424 before `\ExecuteOptions...` in line 35 and now it works with pdflatex.

Comment: That appears to work for me as well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution provided by ChristianHupfer and alwaysask.

1. Remove the stray 'd' that somehow made it to the end of `\ProcessOptions` in line 36.
2. Move the nine `\DeclareOption` commands (lines 424-432) in front of `\ExecuteOptions` (line 35).

It works now for LaTeX and PdfLaTeX.

Thank you both very much!

Comment: Same issue, solution worked. The extraneous "d" seems to be gone now but they still haven't relocated those \DeclareOption statements. Come on AIAA!