# AIAA's LaTeX zip only includes a .cls and the included template doesn't compile

Tags: packages, compiling, document-classes, aiaa

My standard proceedure for using a new .cls or .sty are as follows: (1) unzip to a common directory and attempt to compile the template tex file typically included. (2) If (1) fails, look for things like README's, .ins, or .dtx files to look at or compile before trying (1) again. (3) if (1) and (2) fail, beg someone for help.

I downloaded the AIAA "latex template" from [here](https://www.aiaa.org/SecondaryTwoColumn.aspx?id=26241) and unzipped it to a local directory to find the following files:

```
AIAA.cls, journalstemp.aux, journalstemp.dvi,journalstemp.log,  
journalstempNotes.bib, journalstemp.pdf, journalstemp.tex.
```

(1) failed. I presumed the README was the .pdf/content of the .tex, but this only includes extensive instructions for the word users, copied and pasted from the word .zip on the same page. I have googled hard and delved deep into the labyrinthine complex which forms the AIAA website, but to no avail. So now (3).

Does anyone else have experience here?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  sadly, i have no experience with aiaa.

Comment: The class file is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

This question turned out to be a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324093/fixing-class-error-latex-error-requirepackage-or-loadclass-in-options-secti) and the solution proposed there has appeared to work.